# Calculating year from total minutes while accounting for leap year

Tags: jquery, math, time

I'm putting together an ICS file generator using jquery. After inputting the Date and time zone I figured it would be easiest to calculate out total minutes then make the timezone conversion to Z-time / UTC-0 / GMT and reconvert the total time into each appropriate time unit (year, month, date, hour and minute).

My question concerns the logic of my function: is this the most effective way to do this calculation, 2018 checks? Keep in mind, every leap year (current year is divisible by 4) has 527040 minutes and the common year (not divisible by 4) has 525600.

```
var timeTot = 1061911800; // for debug
var uyear = 1; // DODGE DIVIDE BY ZERO ERROR

while (timeTot >= 525600 || timeTot >= 527040) {
  if (uyear % 4 != 0) { // is common year?
    timeTot -= 525600;
    uyear++;
  } else if (uyear % 4 == 0) { // is leap year?
    timeTot -= 527040;
    uyear++;
  } else {
    //infinite loop!
    timeTot = 0;
  }
}
uyear -= 1; // UNDODGE DIVIDE BY ZERO
// uyear is 2018 ( 1/1/2019@00:00 UTC-6 )
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Right but can this constructor convert the Date/time/time zone to Z / UTC-0 for use in the ICS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could get rid of some of the if statements:

```
var timeTot = 1061911800; // for debug
var uyear = 1; // DODGE DIVIDE BY ZERO ERROR
var difference = 527040-525600 // you can name this differently

while (timeTot >= 525600 || timeTot >= 527040) {
  timeTot -= 525600
  if(uyear % 4 == 0) {
    timeTot -= difference
  }
  uyear++
}
uyear -= 1; // UNDODGE DIVIDE BY ZERO
// uyear is 2018 ( 1/1/2019@00:00 UTC-6 )
```

This one is a little bit shorter as well.

Although, now that I think about it, you could also go about it like this:

```
var timeTot = 1061911800; // for debug
var uyear = 1; // DODGE DIVIDE BY ZERO ERROR
var difference = 527040-525600 // you can name this differently

var leaps = Math.floor(timeTot/527040) // amount of leap years

uyear = leaps + Math.floor((timeTot-leaps*527040)/525600)
```

So basically you first find out how many leap years there has been in timetTot and then figure out how many normal years remain after subtracting the minute length of the leap years. I haven't tested it but I think something like that should also work.

Comment: Totally valid points! There are a lot of improvements to be made and some of my logic is flawed (why two logic operations when one is larger than the other?). But is there a better operator/logic check/arithmetic than a while loop and if statement to check for a result divisible by 4 having a different value?

Comment: Oh yeah, calculate the number of leap years contained within timeTot and do a 2nd calculation—calculating over 504 leap years it may introduce an error somewhere but this is much more effective logic